# Constructor with output-parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, out

today I saw a snipped that looked really horrible to me, but unfortunetly I cannot simply change it, so I wonder if I can bypass this somehow. I have a class with a constructor that has an output-parameter for success. But that looks really ugly to me. And now when deriving from this class I have to take this param with me- if I want to or not.

```
class ClassA {
    ClassA(out bool success) {...}
}

class B: ClassA {
    // call the constructor from ClassA but without the out-param
}
```

So I´d know if its good practise or if not how I can avoid declaring the out-param from ClassB.

Comment: No, you cannot bypass it.

Comment: @Steven: In some cases, it may be necessary for a failed constructor attempt to convey information about what parts of an operation did or did not succeed.  Consider, for example, an object whose constructor accepts a handle to an unmanaged object and is supposed to encapsulate it.  If the constructor throws an exception, it may be imperative that the caller release the unmanaged object if the constructor didn't, and equally imperative that the caller not release the object if the constructor did.

Comment: @Steven: If whenever a constructor failed the system would immediately call `ICleanupFailedConstructor.Cleanup()` if the type being constructed implemented it, type constructors could avoid imposing such burdens on their callers, but alas no such feature as yet exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the design of that class is broken anyway, so let's break it a bit more (**NOTE!** I do not recommend this approach!):

```
void Main()
{

}

public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(out bool success)
    {
        success = true;
    }
}

public class B: ClassA
{
    private static bool success;

    // call the constructor from ClassA but without the out-param
    public B()
        : base(out success)
    {
    }
}
```

Other than that, the closest you can get is making a factory method:

```
public class B : ClassA
{
    public static B Create()
    {
        bool success;
        var result = new B(out success);
        if (success)
            return result;
        // TODO: Dispose result?
        throw new StupidProgrammerException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Factory-method would be best practice from my point of view, nice idea

Answer (score 4):

While passing `ref` or `out` parameters to a constructor is ugly, there are some types where attempts to create a usable instance will have side-effects, and might fail after some of those side-effects have already occurred.  If it is not possible to construct a valid object, the only ways via which the constructor can pass information to the caller are by storing it in a `threadstatic` field, encapsulating it within the thrown exception, storing or feeding it to a passed-in object or delegate, or writing it to a `ref`/`out` parameter.  Of those, only the `ref`/`out` parameter makes obvious the existence of information with which the client code should be doing something.

The existence of `ref` or `out` parameters is often an indication that a constructor should be `protected`, and that outside code should go through a factory methods which ensure that if an exception is thrown the passed-out object will get used suitably.  For a class to reasonably support inheritance, however, it must offer at least one constructor which is visible outside it.  Having that constructor use an `out` or `ref` parameter may be the least evil way for a class to let a caller know what things will need cleaning up if construction fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    protected ClassA(out bool success)
    {
        success = true;
    }
}

class B : ClassA
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static bool success; // static to use in base(out success) call

    public bool Success
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public B()
        : base(out success)
    {
        Success = success;
        success = false; // reset value
    }
}
```

It's ugly, but at least you get rid of the out parameter if so you want.

Comment: You don't even need the [ThreadStatic]. Since `success` is never used, there's no chance of introducing any concurrency bugs when you remove the [ThreadStatic]. And you don't have to reset it.

Comment: Or consider throwing an exception when `success` is false (but in that case you do need the [ThreadStatic]).

Comment: @Steven well base class init `success` and I store it in property, just in case. I've thinked about throw exception, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about the value of the `out` parameter, in newer versions of C# you can declare an `out` variable inline and you can choose to do nothing with it:

```cs
class B : ClassA
{
    B() : base(out bool ignore) { }
}
```

You can go further and use the special discard name `_` to let the compiler know you won't use the variable. This way you don't even need to declare its type:

```cs
class B : ClassA
{
    B() : base(out _) { }
}
```