# Proper usage of out parameter in C#

Tags: c#, out

Edit: I know this is typically not done, and is on the lines of bad practice, but my hand is sort of forced in this specific usage case. My other alternative (as I see it fro this case) is to route an event through my singleton (not shown) and subscribe to it- but that seems like it would be 'bad form' as well.

I have a question on an out parameter before I go throwing it into my code and messing things up.

```
class myExam
{
    private bool faulted = true;

    public myExam(string demo) { .... }

    public myExam(string one, string two, string three) { .... }

    public myExam(string demo, out bool success)
    {
        try
        {
            // bool to hard kill processing
            while(faulted)
            {

                // do stuff

                // no fault, out true
                success = faulted;

                // break loop
                faulted = false;

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            // fault, set faulted, return out false
            faulted = false;
            success = faulted;
            // Correct? ^
        }
    }
}
```

My question is this. A) is that correct way to return in the catch, and B) in the try, provided no issues, will that output true? My assumption is that I've read/understood everything correctly, but again, before messing things up I was wondering if I could get a check on my logic. idk if this is a bad thing to ask or not as if it is correct, then the answer is just "yes" :/

Comment: I think you didn't clearly understand how `try catch` works. I'd suggest you to see examples.

Comment: That is an absolutely pointless comment- how about what is wrong with it- I removed my error handles for simplicity.

Comment: and yes, I know that once it drops into the catch it will break the loop, but i need to still change the bool before I pass it out, or as I understand it

Comment: A) The correct way to "return" something using an `out` parameter is to assign a value to the parameter. B) No, it will output `false`, you just set `faulted` to `false` and then you assign the value on to `success` as well.

Comment: Question: What is the purpose of the loop, since it seems you break out of it after 1 iteration anyway.

Comment: 1) I don't think you can use `out` parameters in constructors, 2) You should either let the exception propagate out, or you should simply `return false;` instead of using `out`. There's very few good use cases for using `out`, and this probably isn't one of them.

Comment: I removed the entire class to make my question simple- I swear I can't win. Some are read only variable set voids, some of them are voids that won't fault the process, but actually display info differently.

Comment: @Luaan You can't *return* anything from a constructor. Using `out` in a constructor is perfectly valid, syntax-wise. Whether it is a good idea or good design is a completely different question. I agree this is not the right usage of an `out` parameter.

Comment: You have an `out` parameter in a constructor, which seems a little odd. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633251/constructor-with-output-parameter suggests I'm not the only one who feels that way. Assuming that `out` *is* a proper design choice for your usage, then I'd suggest the easier approach would be to add a `finally` block that sets `success = faulted;`.

Comment: @alykins: Please don't act like you're being attacked. You specifically asked people to look at your logic, please don't be angry that people actually did.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is most likely not a good usage of constructors either :D That's why I suggested this should simply be a method returning `bool`.

Comment: From what I've read you can, and I know that normally it isn't done, but in this case that would mean re-writing the entire class and everything else that touches.

Comment: from MSDN site you can- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ec6fb3f-dd67-48c5-9655-1c479323fafa/can-a-constructor-return-a-value?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @alykins That might actually be quite a good idea. Just from this snippet, it seems like bad design. And note that you can break out from a loop using `break;`.

Comment: I'm not 'angry' about the replies- I'm frustrated with the first comment that wasn't constructive and then the seemingly endless battle I can't win- if I post too much people get annoyed, if I make it simple people get annoyed and question either my research or knowledge- it's rather frustrating. I have looked into this for quite some time. I'll add that I know this is typically not done, and is a very specific usage case, and my hand is kind of forced- my other alternative is to try and work an event trigger through my singleton but I don't want to do that if it's this simple.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I still wonder why you have that loop though, it seems completely unnecessary to me. It would probably be much better to have just this inside the try-block: `(do something) success=true;`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks. I didn't want to throw it in w/o someone else at least glancing at my logic thought and break everything else in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly different suggestion, but why not have a LoadSuccess property on your object, e.g.

```
public class MyExam {
   public bool LoadSuccess { get; private set; }

   public MyExam() {
      //If not loadeded happily set the LoadSuccess property in here.
   }
}
```

This makes your code slightly less unexpected than an out parameter from a constructor.

---

The above would address the code in the way that you have it structured, but for me, if there has been an error, then an exception should be thrown and handled in the calling code.

Take a case where another developer down the line calls this code but does not evaluate the 'success' boolean after the constructor call.  What happens then - will the code continue happily?  Probably not.

Comment: That actually will totally fix my issue- thank you so much for that different perspective. I can now just nix the out idea. Awesome idea! I was so used/focused to just seeing the object as wrapped up and having all it's properties private I didn't think to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your questions so we can end this then.

**A) is that correct way to return in the catch**

As I said in a comment, the correct way to get an `out` parameter to "return" a value is to assign to it. So, yes, assigning a value to the `success` parameter in the catch (and not further changing it) will make the constructor "return" that value in that parameter.

**B) in the try, provided no issues, will that output true?**

Yes, provided you make sure to set `success` somewhere else, perhaps to begin with. Otherwise the compiler will think you fail to set the parameter in all cases and complain.

*(with the code as shown)*

---

Provided you cannot or won't change the code to drop the out parameter as suggested in the comment, and the loop is there only to get success to be true, I would simplify the code:

```
public myExam(string demo, out bool success)
{
    success = false;
    try
    {
        // do stuff

        // no fault, out true
        success = true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

However, I would probably also make sure to *only* handle exceptions you know can occur. Such a catch-everything block is wrong on so many levels that *that* is not a good recommendation.

Comment: That was the reasoning for the loop- faults that won't error everything out but have some other error can still return true (ie those faults do something else) whereas in that catch they are completely fubar and need to throw false. But I will take your suggestion into consideration- I may be over-thinking the 'hard kill' aspect.

Comment: @alykins I've fixed a couple of things in my question, specifically I changed the condition of the "Yes" in B) since you will get a compiler error with the code as shown, unless you ensure `success` is set in all cases (example, set it to false in the start of the constructor). I also changed the code below a bit to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I missed 'what-if' it fails on that. Odd though-- and I guess maybe a reason why this isn't done on constructors normally-- is I would have thought that it would have thrown an unhanded exception on the other end when I try to call it-

Answer (score 2):

Out parameters must be assigned before the method returns so all possible paths must set the value of `success`. You may want to add a `finally` clause and set the value there or you can set it to a default value to start with and then go ahead with the rest of the method.

If I paste your code in linqpad I actually get a compile error:

```
The out parameter 'success' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method
```

On a side note, your use of `faulted` is a little strange, because when there are not faults `success` is `false`.

Comment: Yes I just saw this after Lasse pointed it out- I don't assign it before the catch so it has no value

Comment: Question for you- I wrote this real quick in notepad- is linqpad like a mini compiler? I've never used it before and thought it was just for LINQ database queries (I don't use LINQ too often, working at understanding/learning it better)

Comment: Linqpad is kind of like a notepad compiler, it allows you to compile and run snippets of code. Very handy tool, particularly for learning C#. You can do most things you can do in a console app.